# django model Foreignkey returning id and not the value as specified in __unicode__

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using django model with Foreignkey as follows:

```
class Types_of_Expenditures(models.Model):
    Expenditure_owner = models.CharField(default="None",max_length=50)
    Expenditure_Type = models.CharField(default="Miscellaneous",max_length=50)
    Expenditure_Type_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Expenditure_Type

class Expenditure(models.Model):
    exp_owner= models.CharField(default='None',max_length=50)
    exp_date = models.DateTimeField("Expenditure_Date")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="MYR",editable=True)
    exp_pocket = models.ForeignKey(Pockets, null=True, blank=True)
    exp_type = models.ForeignKey(Types_of_Expenditures)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('exp_date', 'description',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Now when i save data in Types of expenditure i am doing :

```
Types_of_Expenditures.objects.get_or_create(Expenditure_owner='a',Expenditure_Type_Description="Default one")
```

and in database data is as :

```
id Expenditure_owner Expenditure_Type Expenditure_type_description
 1                a                   Miscellaneous   default one
```

but when i add anything to Expenditure data is saved with data in exp_type as 1 but it should be Miscellaneous because in def **unicode** i am returning Expenditure_type .

Here s how i am using formset to save data for Expenditure model:

```
ExpFormSet = modelformset_factory(Expenditure,extra=10,max_num=10,
                fields=('exp_date', 'description','exp_type','amount','currency','exp_pocket'),
                can_delete=False,form=ExpenditureForm)

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ExpFormSet(request.POST,queryset=Expenditure.objects.filter(exp_owner=request.user))
if formset.is_valid():
    print "printing formset",formset
    formset.save(commit=True)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    expenditureType = cd.get('exp_type')
    print "Expenditure Type entered is ",expenditureType
return index(request)
```

What i am doing in index view:

```
Expenditure_list = Expenditure.objects.order_by('-exp_date').filter(exp_owner=request.user)
print "Expenditure List is : ", Expenditure_list.values_list()
```

Now output of this expenditure view as value of Expenditure_list.values_list() is **(please see last value which is 1 i.e. value of exp_type )** :

```
Expenditure List is :  [(3, u'a', datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 15, 32, 10), u'test', 1.0, u'MYR', u'pocket', 1)]
```

What do i expect :

```
Expenditure List is :  [(3, u'a', datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 15, 32, 10), u'test', 1.0, u'MYR', u'pocket', u'Miscellaneous')]
```

Can anyone help what could be the problem here ?

I feel This question might be wrong may be it will save only foreign key there i.e. id and in order to get expenditure type i need to retrieve it using Types_of_Expenditure.objects.get(pk="Key as in list")

but not sure if there s an alternate way ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand this question. Exactly what output are you getting, what code are you running to get that output, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added what i am getting and what i expect , Please advice if you need me to explain further , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. You seem to be expecting `values_list` to return the `__unicode__` of a related model, but there's no reason to think it would: as the name implies, it returns the *values* only, and the value of a ForeignKey field is just the ID.

You can supply a list of fieldnames to `values_list` and traverse the relationship there, if you want:

```
Expenditure.objects.values_list('description', 'amount', 'exp_type__ Expenditure_Type')
```

Comment: Hey yes i understand i was thinking ForeignKey should return value as in __unicode__ . i am still learning django .. Sorry for all the trouble and your post really helped , Thanks